# How to simplify a nested binomial sum.

Tags: binomial-theorem

If $$(1 + x + x^2)^n = \sum^{2n}_{k=0} b_k x^{2k}$$

Then find $\sum^{2n}_{k= 0} b_k$

$$((1+ x) + x^2)^n = \sum^n_{k=0}{n\choose k} x^{2k}(1+x)^{n-k} = \sum^n_{k=0}{n\choose k} x^{2k}\sum^{n-k}_{r = 0} {n-k \choose r} x^r = \sum^n_{k=0}\sum^{n-k}_{r = 0}{n\choose k} x^{2k} {n-k \choose r} x^r   $$

$${n\choose k}{n-k \choose r} = \dfrac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}\dfrac{(n-k)!}{k! (n-k - r)!} = \dfrac{n!}{(k!)^2 (n-k-r)!}$$

So,

$$\sum^n_{k=0}\sum^{n-k}_{r = 0}{n\choose k} x^{2k} {n-k \choose r} x^r = \sum^n_{k=0}\sum^{n-k}_{r = 0} x^{2k+r}\dfrac{n!}{(k!)^2 (n-k-r)!}$$

I don't have much idea what to do now to do now. Is the question even correct ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x^{k}$ in the first expression as opposed to $x^{2k}$? Also are you sure the sum you want to find is only up to $n$ and not $2n$, I.e. $\sum_{k=0}^{2n}b_k$?

Comment: @AnuragA I posted the question as it is.

Comment: Something's wrong in your assumptions, since $\sum b_k x^{2k}$ is an even function but $(1+x+x^2)^n$ is not.

Comment: Assuming
$$ (1+x+x^2)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} b_k x^{\color{red}{k}} \tag{1}$$
we may notice that the LHS is a palyndromic polynomial, hence the RHS is a palindromic polynomial as well and $b_k = b_{2n-k}$. It is straightforward to notice that

Comment: $$ b_0+b_1+\ldots+b_{2n-1}+b_{2n} = \text{RHS}_{x=1} =3^n\tag{2}$$
hence the problem boils down to finding $b_n$, that is 
$$\begin{eqnarray*} b_n =[x^0]\left[1+\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^n &=& [x^0]\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^k\\&=&\sum_{\substack{0\leq k \leq n \\ k\text{ even}}}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{k/2}\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$
leading to:
$$ b_0+b_1+\ldots+b_n = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\Big[3^n - \sum_{\substack{0\leq k \leq n \\ k\text{ even}}}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{k/2}\Big]}.\tag{4} $$

Comment: Moved to comments due to revenge downvotes.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Revenge who ?

Comment: @123: I cannot be sure about the identity of the downvoter but my suspects are towards an user I had a disagreement. You did not seem really interested in the proposed solution so I guess it is fine in the comments space.